# Verify that every button is clicked

Tags: java, button, click, verify

When a button in Column A is clicked, it displays either "0" and "1". I'd like to verify that all buttons are clicked via the Submit button. My code works, however, if the first button in the column has a value in it, then the following buttons aren't verified.

```
    if (id==R.id.Submit){
        for(int i=0; i<colA.length; ){
            if (((colA[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colA[i].getText()==("1")))){

                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Please enter all values for Column A.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a counter such as this, to count the number of buttons clicked and match it with the total number of buttons to be clicked in the column

```
if (id==R.id.Submit){
int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<colA.length; i++ ){
        if (((colA[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colA[i].getText()==("1")))){
          counter++;
        }

    }

  if(counter==colA.length){
           //all have been clicked

        }
else{
  System.out.println("Please enter all values for Column A.");

 }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are `break`ing out of the `for` loop no matter what. In the `if`, what you want to do is `continue` instead of break. That statement will break out of the current iteration in the `for` loop and go to the next iteration, whereas `break` exits the loop entirely.

```
if (id==R.id.Submit){
    for(int i=0; i<colA.length; ){
        if (((colA[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colA[i].getText()==("1")))){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter all values for Column A.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```